# Better design pattern for country specific implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, dependency-injection

In our application, we have a common code base for X country now we are adding support for Y country using polymorphism.

Let's take this example:

```
public abstract class GradeListModelBase
{
    public abstract void CalculateGrade();

    public virtual IEnumerable<dynamic> GetGrade()
    {
         //logic to get grade common for X and Y country.
    }
}

public class GradeListModelForX : GradeListModelBase
{
    public override void CalculateGrade()
    {
         //logic to get grade for X
    }
}

public class GradeListModelForY : GradeListModelBase
{
    public override void CalculateGrade()
    {
         //logic to get grade for Y
    }
}

public class GradeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult List(GradeListModelBase model)
    {
         model.CalculateGrade();
         model.GetGrade();
         return View("List", model)
    }
}
```

Now I want to achieve that when GradeController is called for country X the ListModelFor X should get injected and same for country Y. I have a context from where I can find which country it is, however, I don't want to keep if-else logic everywhere while injecting the models.

Is there any better approach to solve this? Design Pattern? Any suggestion which could help.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow factory approach,

Create factory for `GradeListModel`

```
public interface IGradeListModelFactory{
      GradeListModelBase GetGradeListModel(string country);
}

public class GradeListModelFactory : IGradeListModelFactory
{
    public GradeListModelBase GetGradeListModel(string country){
        GradeListModelBase gradeListModelBase = null;
        switch(country){
            case "x":
                    gradeListModelBase = new GradeListModelForX();
                break;
            case "y":
                    gradeListModelBase = new GradeListModelForY();
                break;
        }
        return gradeListModelBase;
    }
}
```

*You can get instance from service locator instead of initializing it, in that case you need to inject service locator instance in factory*

Now register `IGradeListModelFactory` in IOC container, and inject it to controller,

```
public class GradeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IGradeListModelFactory _gradeListModelFactory;
    public GradeController(IGradeListModelFactory gradeListModelFactory){
        _gradeListModelFactory = gradeListModelFactory;
    }

    public ActionResult List()
    {
        string country = // identify country
        GradeListModelBase model = _gradeListModelFactory.GetGradeListModel(country);

         model.CalculateGrade();
         model.GetGrade();
         return View("List", model)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one question when we have a model posted [HttpPost] then how can we achieve this?

Comment: @KunalKhivensara For this case you need to create custom model binder, in that identify country from the request and get instance of `GradeListModel` and bind properties to instance

Comment: I will try to implement this today and let you know the outcome! Thank you :)